# Create dynamic object hierarchy for Json serialization via Linq

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

Given a database structure:

```
| Context | Resource | TypeCode | Value               |
|---------|----------|----------|---------------------|
| Home    | Header   |          | Welcome to the site |
| Home    | Footer   |          | copyright company   |
| Error 1 |          |          | Error!              |
| UPC     | 55       | Name     | Product             |
| UPC     | 55       | Weight   | 10                  |
```

I need to be able to generate this Json:

```
{
  "Home": {
    "Header": "Welcome to the site",
    "Footer": "copyright company"
  },
  "Error1": "Error!",
  "UPC": {
    "55": {
      "Name": "Product",
      "Weight": "10"
    }
  }
}
```

I'll be using this to feed translations to angular-translate. Value is already set to the target language's value. I've seen various examples of this type of serialization, but they all assume a uniform depth of the target values.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
List<List<string>> a = /*parse ur data to this*/;
foreach(var pa in a){
  dynamic r = getDynamicObject(pa /*List<string>*/);
  string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.SerializeObject(r);
  /*you might have ur string*/
}

/*separate function*/
GetDynamicObject(IEnumerable<string> a){
 dynamic r = new ExpandoObject();
 if(a.count > 2){
  return (r as Dictionary<string,  object>).Add(a.First(), GetDynamicObject(a.Skip(1)));
  } 
  else {
    return (r as Dictionary<string,  object>).Add(a.First(), a.Last());
 }
}
```

note:-I have written this code here only might contain compile time errors.